# Syntax error token

Tags: java

I am trying to read file, bet i got sintax error, and i dont know where is the problem.

```
public class teksta_datnes {
    BufferedReader lasa = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("teksts.txt"));
    String = rezultats = lasa.readLine();
    System.out.println(rezultats);
    lasa.close();
    //PrintWriter raksta = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter('uzdevums.txt'));
    //raksta.println(
}
```

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
Thanks!

Comment: put your code inside a method (or constructor).

Comment: You need to look at some Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
String = rezultats = lasa.readLine();
```

to

```
String rezultats = lasa.readLine();
```

there is one `=` to much in that line. 
First comes the `datatype` then the `name` and then the `assignment`.

Furthermore define a method to do the whole work:

```
public class teksta_datnes {

  public void printSomething() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader lasa = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("teksts.txt"));
    String rezultats = lasa.readLine();
    System.out.println(rezultats);
    lasa.close();
  }
}
```

An `IDE` should recognize that and show you the affected line.

Answer (score 1):

`String = rezultats = lasa.readLine();` notice that `=` after String. Also ,You've just put code in class definition .